# Cannot use C++ QQuickPaintedItem Singleton in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have to create a C++ singleton class, but it doesn't work in qml.

```
#include "myimage.h"
MyImage::MyImage(QQuickPaintedItem *parent)
{

}

MyImage* MyImage::myImage = new MyImage;

MyImage *MyImage::instance()
{
    return myImage;
}

void MyImage::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    QRectF target(10.0, 20.0, 80.0, 60.0);
    QRectF source(0.0, 0.0, 70.0, 40.0);
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform, true );
    painter->drawImage(target, this->m_Image, source);
}

const QImage &MyImage::getM_Image() const
{
    return m_Image;
}

void MyImage::setM_Image(const QImage &mimage)
{
    if (mimage != m_Image) {
        m_Image = mimage;
        emit m_ImageChanged();
    }
}//This is my singleton class.
```

Then I register it in main.cpp.

```
QObject *getMySingletonImage(QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine)
{
    Q_UNUSED(engine)
    Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine)

    return MyImage::instance();
}
...
qmlRegisterSingletonType<MyImage>("s0.image", 1, 0, "MyImage", &getMySingletonImage);
```

In QML:

```
import s0.image 1.0
MyImage{

            }
```

I cannot run the program successfully.

```
qrc:/Camview_Page.qml:371:13: Element is not creatable.
```

Actually, I use the singleton class both in my backend and qml.
In my backend, I will get QImage type images but not be saved local, so I cannot use QUrl and I only figure out this method.

Expectation:
My backend pass images of QImage type to the singleton class, my singleton class realize the method of paint, my qml show the image.

BTW...my backend gets images from camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A singleton is already created for QML so you get that error message since by using "{}" you are trying to create the object.

In this case it is enough to set a parent and the size:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

import s0.image 1.0

Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Component.onCompleted: {
        MyImage.parent = root.contentItem
        MyImage.width = 100
        MyImage.height = 100
    }
}
```

If you want to create a binding for example set `anchors.fill: parent` then you can use the [`Binding`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-binding.html) component, if you want to hear any signal then you must use [`Connections`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-connections.html) component.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

import s0.image 1.0

Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Binding{
        target: MyImage
        property: "parent"
        value: root.contentItem
    }
    Binding {
        target: MyImage
        property: "anchors.fill"
        value: MyImage.parent
    }
    Connections{
        target: MyImage
        function onWidthChanged(){
            console.log("width:", MyImage.width)
        }
        function onHeightChanged(){
            console.log("height:", MyImage.height)
        }
    }
}
```